# dpkg was interrupted

Tags: command-line, configure

When I wanted to install `matlab` support, it asked me to write the location of `matlab` where it is installed. After typing the location, terminal was blocked did not show anything for a while. Then I closed the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

Now, when I say upgrade or typing the code above it shows me an error below. What to do?

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

---

from `man dpkg`

```
--configure package...|-a|--pending
        Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet
        configured.  If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all
        unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.

        To reconfigure a package which has already been configured, try
        the dpkg-reconfigure(8) command instead.

        Configuring consists of the following steps:

          1. Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back up the old
             conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

          2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
```

Comment: now it is ok, but when i am trying install matlab-support, after typing location it says "Preconfiguring packages ..." and doing nothing

Comment: Give him more time.

Comment: Or ask a new question, because this is a new problem =)